# How to consider a variable that has both random and fixed values?

Tags: regression

I have an experiment in which we want to measure the effect of a medication on mean arterial pressure (MAP). We have 3 conditions for each patient: placebo (no treatment), fixed standard dosis (100mg) and a device that constantly measures the MAP and administers a small dosis of medication according to the MAP measured. After 2 hours, we measure the change on MAP on this three conditions. We want to include the total dosis administered as a predictor variable. As this variable has either a fixed amount (0 for no treatment and 100mg for standard treatment) or a variable amount (miligrams according to each patient), my question is: how should I classify this variable when building a regression model (either random or fixed)?
Thanks a lot for your responses.

Comment: IThis is tricky - for the placebo and standard conditions, including the condition predictor in your model is sufficient to tell you what dose was used. In other words, condition = dose for these two treatments, so it seems redunandat to add information on the dose for them in the model since dose is explicit from the condition name.

Comment: Given my comment above, I wonder though if you could include a categorical variable, DoseCat, in your model defined like this: DoseCat = 0 if Total Dose = 0 mg, DoseCat = 1 if Total Dose > 0 mg but < 100 mg, DoseCat = 2 if Total Dose = 100 mg and DoseCat = 3 if Total Dose > 100 mg.

Comment: If you have a model like MAP ~ Condition + DoseCat, where DoseCat is as described above, you are essentially comparing the differences between conditions (in terms of mean MAP) at the same dose.  But you'll need to do some thinking in terms of defining DoseCat to make sure your model captures the conditions to be compared for the meaningful doses.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I was worried that I should transform my continuous variable into a categorical, as that would decrease the amount of data on the category that is continuous. I also ask my Statistics teacher. Unfortunately, it seems that the only solution if you want to take that into account is to make 2 models, one for the three categories, and a separate model only for your the category in which doses are variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, there is additional data; age, body weight, route of administration and mechanism of action of the drug. For example, if the mechanism of action is direct vascular arterial smooth muscle relaxation, as it would be for dipyradmole, as a first approximation for intravenous dosing, the drug effect would be roughly proportional to body weight because blood volume is roughly proportional to body mass. For furosemide, dosing is roughly proportional to metabolic rate (i.e., oxygen consumption or GFR), which in turn is roughly proportional to the 3/4$^{ths}$ power of body mass. Suggest a starting point for scaling formulas and regression is [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Carl_Wesolowski/post/what_is_the_novel_specific_marker_for_chronic_renal_failure/attachment/59d6200a79197b807797e84e/AS%3A288217535401995%401445727823840/download/2006_IEEE_NSS_MIC_Wesolowski.pdf).

In effect, although a 100 mg dosage may seem like a constant, in terms of how the body 'views' that dosage, it is actually a variable. I would follow the procedure outlined in the linked paper with the caveat being that only two time samples are being regressed, that is unless the temporal data for the variable administration is available. Also, the effects are rather more likely proportional so the effects are more likely products of variables to powers of parameters than sums of linear terms. If the routes of administration are oral, that introduces a convolution type temporal delay between ingestion and blood levels as well as an inefficiency of absorption that may deliver only a fraction of the total dosage.

Divulge a bit more information if you want a more exact opinion, please.